# What is the maximum Event Value for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Should I be worried about hitting `integer_max` for Google Analytic's `Event Value` if I am tracking values that are 5, 6, or even 7 digits long? The main purpose is determining the averages of values entered by users.

I can foresee that the `Event Value` for this field will add up very quickly. There will be thousands of values, all of them will be large values, and I am worried that Google Analytics will hit a max integer limit.

One solution that I can come up with is to divide all values by 100,000 or so before tracking them to make hitting the upper limit much harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol accepts signed, 64-bit integers for all parameters of type integer:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#integer

So as long as you're not sending so many event hits that they add up to larger than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, you should be fine.